# excel change diagram characteristics with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, diagrams

I have many diagrams in excel and I need to change their look. I wrote this cscript in VBA but it is not working:

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
For i = 1 To 28
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm " & i).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm " & i).Line.Visible = msoFalse
Next i
End Sub
```

With this script I am trying to change the frame line to no frame line. But it is not working and I cannto find the bug. Moreover, I need to change the name of the y-axis. Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: @pnuts: do you mean if I have the number "1" (if the numbering of my charts starts from 1) or if it is named "Diagramm"? The "Diagramm" is the "Chart" for the german version of excel.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by frame line, your code as-is works for me by removing the object border.

Y-axis is:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Title Here"
```